# Does CodeIgniter's $this->image_lib->resize() function return the new image size?

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing, codeigniter-2

CodeIgniter has a nice image manipulation class. I'm setting an image to be resized to a max of 200x200 pixels, with "master_dim" enabled to keep the aspect ratio the same. However, I don't see a way to get the new size of the image after it's done so that I can store it in the  database. Does it not do this? Or do I have to use PHP's getimagesize() to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->image_lib->resize()` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

You will need to use `getimagesize` on the new image to get its size after the resize.

Comment: Thanks. Seems silly that they didn't return an array with the new image info, including the new file size.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm not sure why it was done that way either :-P